# Is there any way to change agm-map theme to dark mode or street-view?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to change angular map theme to dark but not able to accomplish.please help..
my code:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"[zoom]="zoom"[class.dark-theme]="isDark" >
```

map.component.ts:

isDark = true;

Answer (score 4):

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"  [styles]="mapStyle === 'dark' ? styleDark : styleLight">
    .
    .
    .
</agm-map>
```

In your ts you will have the logic to toggle the styles or you can set a default style

```
 public darkStyle = [
        {
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "hue": "#ff4400"
            },
            {
              "saturation": -100
            },
            {
              "lightness": -4
            },
            {
              "gamma": 0.72
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "road",
          "elementType": "labels.icon"
        },
        {
          "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "hue": "#0077ff"
            },
            {
              "gamma": 3.1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "hue": "#000000"
            },
            {
              "gamma": 0.44
            },
            {
              "saturation": -33
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "poi.park",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "hue": "#44ff00"
            },
            {
              "saturation": -23
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "hue": "#007fff"
            },
            {
              "gamma": 0.77
            },
            {
              "saturation": 65
            },
            {
              "lightness": 99
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "gamma": 0.11
            },
            {
              "weight": 5.6
            },
            {
              "saturation": 99
            },
            {
              "hue": "#0091ff"
            },
            {
              "lightness": -86
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "transit.line",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "lightness": -48
            },
            {
              "hue": "#ff5e00"
            },
            {
              "gamma": 1.2
            },
            {
              "saturation": -23
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "transit",
          "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "saturation": -64
            },
            {
              "hue": "#ff9100"
            },
            {
              "lightness": 16
            },
            {
              "gamma": 0.47
            },
            {
              "weight": 2.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "water",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "color": "#222222"
            }
          ]
        },
      ];

      public defaultStyle = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can add](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#styles) a theme doing:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"[zoom]="zoom" [styles]="customTheme">
```